# How to change DB connections on the fly with GraphQL?

Tags: database, graphql, database-connection, apollo-server

We have a GraphQL server setup which uses the exact same set of GraphQL calls on different client systems.  These clients have the same exact tables/structures which do not change.

I'd like to make a GraphQL calls which indicate which DB connection to use.  OR if there is a similar alternative with GraphQL, I'm all ears.

I've been Googling, forum diving, and document scanning for a while...

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to create a [directives](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/schema/creating-directives/#implementing-schema-directives).

```js
const typeDefs = gql`

  directive @db(client: DbClient) on FIELD_DEFINITION

  type DbClient {
     DB_CLIENT_1
     DB_CLIENT_2
  } 

  type Query {
    users: [User] @db
  }
`;
```

```js
// Directive


// db client connection config 
const dbConnectionConfig = {
   DEFAULT : {...},
   DB_CLIENT_1: {...},
   DB_CLIENT_2: {...}
}

class DbClientDirective extends SchemaDirectiveVisitor {
  public visitFieldDefinition(field) {
    const { resolve = defaultFieldResolver } = field;
    const { client } = this.args;

    field.args.push({
      name: 'client',
      type: GraphQLString
    });

    field.resolve = async function (
      source,
      { client, ...otherArgs },
      context,
      info,
    ) {


      let connectionConfig = dbConnectionConfig.DEFAULT;
      if(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(dbConnectionConfig, client)) {
        connectionConfig = dbConnectionConfig[client];
      }

      /**
       create a DB client with the given config. Even you can persist the DB connection is a hashMap such that you don't need to establish a new connection every time.
      **/

      const dbSession = new DbClient(connectionConfig);

      // put the dbSession in a context such that it can be used by the resolver.

      context.dbSession = dbSession;
      return resolve.call(this, source, otherArgs, context, info);
    };

    field.type = GraphQLString;
  }
}
```

```js
// UserResolver.js

const UserResolver = {
  Query: {
    users(async (parent, args, context, info) => {
      const dbSession = context.dbSession;
      // use the dbSession to fetch the results. Note, here resolve need not to know about the db client details.

      return dbSession.findAll();
    }
}
```

```js
const resolvers = merge(
  UserResolver
);

const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  schemaDirectives: {
    date: DbClientDirective
  }
});

server.listen().then(({ url }) => {
  console.log(` Server ready at ${url}`);
});
```

You can now pass client argument to a user query to indicate which DB connection to use.

Example 1 - this will use DEFAULT as DB client

```
query {
   users {
      name
      userId 
   }
}
```

Example 2 - this will use DB_CLIENT_1 as DB client

```
query {
   users(client: DB_CLIENT_1) {
      name
      userId 
   }
}
```